# Laravel Failed to attach many-to-many table

Tags: laravel

Why I have got 3 values when I attach "dresscodes"?

```
$event->dresscode()->attach($request->get('dressCodesValue'));
```

this is error message

```
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'dress_codes_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `dress_codes_events` (`dress_codes_id`, `events_id`) values (1,2, 28))
```

Here is a relation of Events table

```
public function dresscode()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(DressCodes::class);
}
```

Here are dresscode value when print out from controller  `$request->get('dressCodesValue')` // 1,2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

**Here is my problem**

When I pass my data into `FormData()` and post it via `axios.post` It's converts my array value into string

**Solution**

just explode string back to array and pass that value into `attach()` method